# Ranking keywords by frequency and date range

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, innodb, ranking

Currently I have around 900,000 entries in the data_article_key_terms table to associate key terms to their respective articles. The goal is to be able to select an arbitrary date range and display the top 15 key terms based on the articles in that date range.

The problem that I'm running in to is that the query that I'm running takes almost 6 seconds, but I need it to be faster than that. I realize that this is relative based on the system that I'm running on and I could use a machine with more power, but I'm trying to optimize it the best I can before I go that route.

I'm using InnoDB as the MySQL storage engine to preserve data integrity. As I understand it MyISAM is faster with count(*), but using that engine is also not an option.

I've also considered storing the key term counts in a table based on fixed time ranges, but that ends up being a lot of data to store and keep track of.

Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to optimize this experience?

I have the following tables:

This table stores article information:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `connection_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `folder_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `influencer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data_article_5930b15a` (`connection_id`),
  KEY `data_article_4e5f642` (`folder_id`),
  KEY `data_article_fbfc09f1` (`user_id`),
  KEY `data_article_43ae76a1` (`influencer_id`),
  KEY `data_article_date` (`date`),
  CONSTRAINT `connection_id_refs_id_b2ae9152` FOREIGN KEY (`connection_id`) REFERENCES `account_connection` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `folder_id_refs_id_e343586a` FOREIGN KEY (`folder_id`) REFERENCES `account_folder` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `influencer_id_refs_id_45cd3615` FOREIGN KEY (`influencer_id`) REFERENCES `data_influencer` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_aca13cc9` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`)
)
```

This table stores key terms:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_keyterm` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `term` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data_keyterm_term` (`term`)
)
```

This table stores the relationship between articles and key terms:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_article_key_terms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyterm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `article_id` (`article_id`,`keyterm_id`),
  KEY `data_article_key_terms_30525a19` (`article_id`),
  KEY `data_article_key_terms_1d848ca4` (`keyterm_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `article_id_refs_id_d87be8f5` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `data_article` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `keyterm_id_refs_id_50d233f8` FOREIGN KEY (`keyterm_id`) REFERENCES `data_keyterm` (`id`)
)
```

This table stores influencers that are associated with the articles:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_influencer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data_influencer_fbfc09f1` (`user_id`),
  KEY `data_influencer_name` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_b1bb5d4f` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`)
)
```

This is the SQL statement I'm using to pull the keywords based on a time range, group them, and order them by frequency:

```
SELECT dk.id, dk.term as term, COUNT(dk.id) as count
FROM data_keyterm dk
INNER JOIN data_article_key_terms dakt ON dakt.keyterm_id = dk.id
INNER JOIN data_article da ON da.id = dakt.article_id
INNER JOIN data_influencer di ON di.id = da.influencer_id
WHERE da.user_id = 1
AND da.date between '2010-08-07' AND '2012-08-07'
AND di.active = True
GROUP BY dk.id
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: Your last SQL statement doesn't look as a valid GROUP BY statement. Can you double check?

Comment: Yes, it's correct this statement runs without problem.

Comment: @Olaf: It's not a valid SQL GROUP BY clause, but [it's valid in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Comment: Edit your question, and paste in the [execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the inner join with a table with 900,000 records and 3 inner join will be take some time to execute. I think you should try some external search engines like solar to obtain the results in quick time

Comment: Can Solr handle searches like this?

Comment: yes it handles. you have u create indexes properly for obtaining results like this

Comment: Thanks for the Solr tip. I ended up using it and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if, in this case, the indexes may not be helping you.  What is the selectivity of the query?  That is, how many article/key combinations are being used?

To optimize performance, I think the query plan should be selecting the articles by user id and date and then doing the joins. And then taking this reduced subset for the additional joins.  I suspect, instead, that it is using indexes throughout.

My first suggestion is to replace the two indexes on userid/date on the articles table with a single index.  The WHERE clause can use this single index to satisfy the condition.  This may simplify and improve the query plan.

Another thing to test is denormalizing the article/key table a bit.  Assuming that the keys and article are created at the same time, add the user id and date to this table.  Then, simply rephrase your query as restrictions on this table.  You can then have a composite index on user id and date.  However, I don't suggest having separate indexes on these fields.